# Definir comportamento da janela em Python quando o mouse estiver sobre e fora dela

Tags: python, gtk

Estou usando PyGTK no Python 2.7 e gostaria de setar `win.set_decorated(False)` quando o mouse estiver fora da janela e `win.set_decorated(True)` quando o mouse estiver sobre a janela. Como fazer?

Comment: Poste o codigo relevante que tem sff, para sabermos como ajudar

Comment: @Miguel, acredito que o código que tenho é irrelevante nesse caso, já que a solução é baseada no estado do mouse sobre a janela, lançando essas duas situações que citei.

Comment: @Miguel, cometi um erro na hora de postar as funções citadas, peço perdão. Editei o post.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhadela. Ha ok então não a tranparecia certo?

Comment: @Miguel obrigado. É sobre tirar as bordas e a barra de título da janela com o set_decorated com base no mouse estar ou não sobre a janela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está com um pequeno bug mas eu vou tentar contornar isso. O evento no entanto está a ser detetado.

```
import gtk

def mouse_enter(win, event):
    win.set_decorated(True)

def mouse_leave(win, event):
    win.set_decorated(False)

win = gtk.Window()
win.set_decorated(False)
win.connect('enter-notify-event', mouse_enter)
win.connect('leave-notify-event', mouse_leave)
win.connect('delete-event', gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

O problema é que ele identifica o rato sobre bordas e a barra de título da janela como não estando sobre a janela.

Pode testar isso com `win.set_opacity(0.5)` no `mouse_leave()` e `win.set_opacity(1)` no `mouse_enter()`, em vez dos `set_decorated()`

Comment: Verdade, o problema está sendo o de corrigir esse colapso da barra de título, pois o leave-notify-event está tratando a barra de título como fora da janela. Estou pesquisando muito aqui para tentar corrigir esse bug, mas sem sucesso ainda. :(

Comment: Talvez não seja possível. Já viu isso em alguma janela? Eu não me llembro de ter visto essa funcionalidade. Entretanto também vou ver se descubro algo

Comment: Então, penso que não seja impossível se eu conseguir mapear as coordenadas da tela e manipular a decoração da janela com base nisso. Mas talvez não seja viável, já que eu consegui fazer o que espero clicando fora da janela e retornando com a decoração ao clicar novamente na janela. É bem menos custoso em termos de processamento.